# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 7]

Tags: python, numpy, regression, linear-regression

I'm learning python for artificial intelligence where i face a problem in implementing linear regression.

I imported:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

on jupyter notebook which worked simply.
then took these arrays:

```
x=np.array([5,2,7,8,70,88,6])
y=np.array([5,7,6,22,3,44,5])

reg=LinearRegression()
```

now, when i want to apply `reshape` and `fit` functions on it, it gives an error, the code is:

```
x=x.reshape(1,-1)
reg.fit(x,y)
```

The error is:

> Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 7]

Comment: What about adding `y = y.reshape(1, -1)` before fitting?

Comment: @ThomasSchillaci yes it worked, and amazingly it when I re-coded x = x.reshape(1,-1), that worked too for which i was struggling from the last half hour

Answer (score 0):

Just to explain it in more detail.

Machine learning models takes 2D input. in your problem you have a one dimensional array

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
x=np.array([5,2,7,8,70,88,6])
y=np.array([5,7,6,22,3,44,5])
x.shape
```

it will display

> (7,)

reshape will help you to provide information in 2D format to the model

```
x.reshape(1,-1)
y.reshape(1,-1)
```

as per the documentation

> Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a
>
> single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

lets train the model

```
reg=LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x,y)
```

Now lets do some prediction, However again while doing prediction , you need to provide the test data in 2d format to model.

```
x_test=np.array([5,2,6,8,20,48,6])
x_test=x_test.reshape(1,-1)
```

lets predict now

```
y_pred=reg.predict(x_test)
y_pred
```

output would be

```
array([[ 5.,  7.,  6., 22.,  3., 44.,  5.]])
```